# returning a value using dbms_output.put_line and out parameter in an Oracle procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What is the difference between printing  a value using  `dbms_output.put_line` and `out` parameter in oracle procedure. Will `dbms_output.put_line` return value to front end?

If not, how to return more than one row to front end using a stored procedure?

Comment: to return more than one row you can use [collection](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/articles-12c) or [Cursor](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets). depends on what you Need. `dbms_output.put_line` is usually used to print out the result and could be useful for displaying information.

Comment: Thanks for your answers all  .Then if i want to display values that is displayed  in an web application how to return it in oracle procedures .in sql server and mysql select is used to display .Even using ref cursor as  out paramter we display using dbms_output.put_line then what to use to return to web application screen

Comment: In the below SP using dbms_output.put_line to return to client(web app screen)

Answer (score 3):

`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` doesn't make much sense in stored procedures or *front end applications* that can't display it (for example, although it makes a valid call in Oracle Forms or Application Express, you won't see anything on the screen).

You don't really expect users to run your procedures in SQL*Plus or TOAD or SQL Developer, do you? Therefore, use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` for debugging purposes.

I guess that this is what you might be using:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test_2
  2    (par_deptno in number)
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select ename from emp where deptno = par_deptno) loop
  6      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.ename);
  7    end loop;
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_test_2(10);
CLARK
KING
MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

If you want to compare it to a procedure that is supposed to return multiple values, then one option is to use `OUT` parameter whose datatype is `SYS_REFCURSOR`. Here's how; you'll notice that it requires some more code - the procedure itself and separate PL/SQL block which will *do something* with its result.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test3
  2    (par_deptno in number, par_emp out sys_refcursor)
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    open par_emp for select * from emp where deptno = par_deptno;
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_emp sys_refcursor;
  3    l_rec emp%rowtype;
  4  begin
  5    p_test3(10, l_emp);
  6
  7    loop
  8      fetch l_emp into l_rec;
  9      exit when l_emp%notfound;
 10      -- You'd do something with those values here; I'm just displaying ENAME
 11      dbms_output.put_line(l_rec.ename);
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /
CLARK
KING
MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Alternatively, for display purposes, in SQL*Plus you might use this:

```
SQL> var l_rec refcursor
SQL> exec p_test3(10, :l_rec);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print l_rec

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE                   SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.1981 00:00:00       2450                    10
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.1981 00:00:00       5000                    10
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.1982 00:00:00       1300                    10

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function uses DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE to display your results column-wise, followed by a new_line character. for example please refer below query.

```
create or replace procedure TEMP_ARRAy_RECORD
is
--type emp_det_tbl IS TABLE OF temp_employee_det%ROWTYPE index by pls_integer;
  type lemp_det IS RECORD 
   ( 
     --l_emp_id int, 
     l_emp_id temp_employee_det.emp_id%type,
     l_city temp_employee_det.city%type,
     l_amount temp_employee_det.amount%type
     );
     TYPE emp_det IS VARRAY(15) OF lemp_det;
  f_emp_det emp_det;
BEGIN 

for i in (select emp_id,city,amount BULK COLLECT into  f_emp_det from temp_employee_det)
loop
dbms_output.put(i.city||',');--fetch all data in single row
dbms_output.put_line(i.city||',');--fetch all data in column wise
exit when SQL%NOTFOUND;
end loop;
dbms_output.new_line;--
end;
execute TEMP_ARRAy_RECORD
```

refer below output will be shown.

```
SQL*Plus statement executed
PL/SQL block executed
CHALISGAON,BHADGAON,PACHORA,JALGAON,NASHIK,
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "front end". If you're running in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, using dbms_output will sent content to a buffer, that's then displayed in a particular window - if [serveroutput](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/oracle-sqlplus-the/0596007469/re85.html) is on for that session.

A properly instrumented program would use a utility such as [Logger](https://github.com/OraOpenSource/Logger) to make debugging notes to a custom table, for later perusal.

OUT parameters in procedures just receive that information into the actual parameter, perhaps some local variable. This could be further processed, displayed on screen, or sent to another procedure.

Answer (score 0):

[DBMS_OUTPUT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html) does not return output in the sense of an I/O stream or function return value. It is a rather basic debugging tool, that works by placing the specified text into a PL/SQL array that can then be retrieved at the end of the call by the client application calling `dbms_output.get_lines()`. Tools such as SQL*Plus and PL/SQL Developer do this automatically, subject to preference settings, but a web front end will not.